# How to define attribute on networkx graph to export it to gephi viz shape

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

I am trying to create nodes and edges with different shape than default (disc for nodes and solid for edges).

I use the viz attribute for the color and it works, but I have no success with the shape. Here are some example for the code I use:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])
attr={1:{'viz':{'shape':'square'}}, 2:{'viz':{'shape':'disc'}}, 3:{'viz':{'shape':'diamond', 'color':{'r': 178, 'g': 34, 'b': 34, 'a': 0}}}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attr)

G.add_edge(1,2, id='ID1', Label='L', viz={'shape':'dashed', 'color':{'r': 178, 'g': 34, 'b': 34, 'a': 0}})
G.add_edge(2,3, id='ID2', label='l')

nx.write_gexf(G, 'g_test_shape' +'.gexf')
```

I am neither able to define the edge Label at networkx graph.

Comment: The `shape` might have been discontinued, but there is a way to _display polygons_, with the `Polygon Shaped Nodes` plugin. The *diamonds* will not diaply the same but this might be some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution.
Not pythonic at all, but it works. You need to install a plugin in Gephi and add a col with int for the sides of the polygons:

https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/polygon-shaped-nodes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28453669)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible. This is what I found at Gephi forum:

> Gephi does not support other shapes than circles for the moment.

The answer is from 2018.

Regards,